# How to setup jenkins for all the private repositories under an organization in GitHub?

Tags: git, github, jenkins

I am trying to set up Jenkins for all private repositories under my organization in GitHub. I could set up a single repository in Jenkins but, how to do it for all the repositories at once? It would be great if you direct me to a blog article if there's any.

**Note:** No GitHub Enterprise Server, Just an organization under GitHub.

Comment: It's a little unclear what you are asking.  You want a single job to be able to clone from multiple repositories at the same time?  Do you need to be able to pull from multiple repositories for a single job or can you have each job just pull from a single repository, and have multiple jobs?

Comment: Is there a way by which I can clone all the private repos under my organization in GitHub in Jenkins?

Comment: Repeating your question in a comment doesn't help to clarify anything.   You need to much more specific about where those repos go and how you are going to use them.  Do you need all of them (2, 5 10 repos?) to be usable at the same time?  To answer the very generic question you have actually asked of whether or not a single jenkins server instance is capable of doing so, yes. Create one build job per repo and set each job to clone a different repo, then run them all.  The Jenkins server instance will have cloned all of your repos.